# Unable to load ONNX model using Rust

Tags: opencv, rust, onnx, yolov8

#### System Information

```
OpenCV version: 4.6.0
Operating System: ubuntu 20.04
GCC version: 9.4.0
Rust Binding Version: 0.86.1
```

#### Detailed description

I have been trying to load an yolov8 onnx model using **readNetFromONNX** and I get the following error.

```
msg: Error { code: -204, message: "OpenCV(4.2.0) ../modules/dnn/include/opencv2/dnn/dnn.inl.hpp:349: error: (-204:Requested object was not found) Required argument \"split\" not found into dictionary in function 'get'\n" }
```

I just want to know how to import the onnx model correctly into the function.

P.S: I used OpenCV Rust bindings for the code but the error is coming from the C++ header.

#### Steps to reproduce

```
use opencv::dnn;


let onnx_path = "/home/Projects/rust-inference-onnx/model.onnx";`


let model: dnn::Net = dnn::read_net_from_onnx(onnx_path).expect("Unable to load model");
```

I need to know how to load the onnx model on Rust with opencv bindings. I have also tried onnx runtime